# What is the best way to access a specific columns of dataframes that are contained in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have a dictionary that is consisted of 1000 dataframes now. I want to access to make changes or sort a specific columns of those dataframes. Can I access their columns directly from dictionary or I have to extract all the dataframes from dictionary first then access them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can access them directly in a list comprehension or a loop by iterating through the keys of your dictionary or directly iterating through the values (which are dataframes).

**For Example**:

```
frames = {i:pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,2)), columns=['col1','col2']) for i in range(5)}
```

`frames` is a dictionary of 5 dataframes with 2 columns each. For instance,

```
>>> frames[0]
       col1      col2
0  0.100050  0.710130
1  0.834157  0.077837
2  0.024547  0.583344
3  0.328716  0.929574
4  0.948498  0.612750
```

Shows the first dataframe

To sort each one by the first column just do:

```
[frames[df].sort_values('col1', inplace=True) for df in frames.keys()]
```

Or

```
[i.sort_values('col1', inplace=True) for i in frames.values()]
```

Then, when you access `frames[0]` again, it will be sorted:

```
>>> frames[0]
       col1      col2
2  0.024547  0.583344
0  0.100050  0.710130
3  0.328716  0.929574
1  0.834157  0.077837
4  0.948498  0.612750
```

All this being said, this isn't the way I would do it. I would concatenate all the frames together with some sort of identifier of what each dataframe is, then do your manipulations on the main dataframe. But what you're trying to achieve is possible in the ways I just outlined.